# error when compiling packages on crosscompile ros for nao robot

Tags: cross-compiling, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having error message when compiling packages rosmake common as in the tutorial (step 7): http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling
I am using Natty 11.04 with diamondback and NAO SDk 1.10.52.

```
anshar@anshar:~/rosfornao/ros/diamondback$ rosmake common
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['common']                                  
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/anshar/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120814-203550
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['common'] to:
['smclib', 'filters', 'xacro', 'test_bond', 'test_nodelet', 'bfl', 'nodelet_topic_tools', 'bondcpp', 'bond', 'tinyxml', 'actionlib', 'yaml_cpp', 'pluginlib', 'nodelet', 'bondpy']
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages common.  This may take a few seconds.
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages             
[ rosmake ] Starting >>> tools/rospack                                          
[ rosmake ] Finished <<< tools/rospack                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib [PASS] [ 0.07 seconds ]                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common [PASS] [ 0.65 seconds ]                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib [PASS] [ 1.26 seconds ]                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime [PASS] [ 1.05 seconds ]                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits [PASS] [ 0.77 seconds ]                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole [PASS] [ 1.13 seconds ]                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization [PASS] [ 0.88 seconds ]           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp [PASS] [ 0.80 seconds ]                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tinyxml [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tinyxml [PASS] [ 0.81 seconds ]                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib [PASS] [ 2.15 seconds ]                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosclean [PASS] [ 0.78 seconds ]                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs [PASS] [ 5.02 seconds ]                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph [PASS] [ 0.74 seconds ]                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosparam [PASS] [ 0.67 seconds ]                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs [PASS] [ 1.10 seconds ]                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmaster [PASS] [ 0.60 seconds ]                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy [PASS] [ 0.61 seconds ]                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit [PASS] [ 0.69 seconds ]                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp [PASS] [ 2.48 seconds ]                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> filters [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bond [PASS] [ 1.28 seconds ]                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                        
[ rosmake ] All 32 linesilters: 1.3 sec ] [ rosou... [ 2 Active 23/39 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  -- OE_CROSS2: sss/opt/naoqi-sdk-1.10.52/nao-cross-toolchain/cross/geode
  [rosbuild] Building package rosout
  [rosbuild] Including /home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build
  cd build && make -l2
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  Linking CXX executable ../rosout
  /home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../rosout] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosout.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/rosfornao/ros/diamondback/ros_comm/tools/rosout/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rosout written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/anshar/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120814-203550/rosout/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosout [FAIL] [ 0.87 seconds ]                         
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rosout. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< filters [PASS] [ 2.22 seconds ]                        
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 25 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/anshar/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120814-203550
```

Looking for assistance.

Thanks. ryan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41304/error-when-compiling-packages-on-crosscompile-ros-for-nao-robot/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-08-13**:
Please add the correct tags to your question, so it can be found (nao, rospack, ...). That looks like a linker error, could you post the complete output in your question?

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2012-08-14**:
I have updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can you try to follow the tutorial exactly as described in the tutorial, step-by-step and just copy&paste the shell scripts/commands into your terminal, leaving everything unchanged?

---

Originally posted by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) with karma: 290 on 2012-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2012-08-15**:
Its exactly the same as the tutorial as only one difference,  I compile the diamond ros for Desktop install, not the RosBone (The source: http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source). tried previously to install the Rod Bones but the rosinstall didnt produce tf and bullet. thanks

**Comment by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) on 2012-08-16**:
you also used a different path which lets me assume that you did not just copy&paste the instructions. there will be a tutorial for fuerte comming soon, maybe you also want to wait for that?

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-01-20**:
when will the fuerte tutorial be released? Btw, I have changed the the path according to the tutorial, but still the same error occured. /media/external/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'